# How many BarButtonItems can be added to UInavigationController

Tags: ios4

How can i add 4 barbuttonitems to uinavigation controller? If i can add then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the answer... 
First of all i created the toolbar, numbers of buttons that i need programmatically.
and added those buttons in NSMutableArray. 
Finally i add this array to my my toolbar item and add it to my view.

That worked perfectly for me. Actually number of button that we add on toolbar depends on the width of UIToolbar. We can add either two, three or four buttons to it if it's within the given width of toolbar. But according to apple reference we should add max two button on it.